# Retriving data from ListView control

Tags: database, vb.net, listview, selectedindex

I have a ListView control set up in details mode with 5 columns. It is populated by code using the following subroutine:

```
            For j = 0 To 14
                cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TeacherName, ClassSubject, BookingDate, BookingPeriod FROM " & SchemaTable.Rows(i)!TABLE_NAME.ToString() & " WHERE (((BookingDate)=" & Chr(34) & Date.Today.AddDays(j) & Chr(34) & ") AND ((UserName)=" & Chr(34) & user & Chr(34) & "));", cn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim itm As ListViewItem
                Dim itms(4) As String
                While dr.Read()
                    itms(0) = dr(0)
                    itms(1) = SchemaTable.Rows(i)!TABLE_NAME.ToString()
                    itms(2) = dr(1)
                    itms(3) = dr(2)
                    itms(4) = dr(3)
                    itm = New ListViewItem(itms)
                    Manage.ManageList.Items.Add(itm)
                End While
            Next
```

Note that this is not the full routine, just the bit that populated the grid.

Now I need to retrieve data from the ListView control in order to delete a booking in my database. I used the following code to retrieve the content of each column:

```
ManageList.SelectedItems(0).Text
```

But it only seems to work on index 0. If I do:

```
ManageList.SelectedItems(3).Text
```

I get this error:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not
>   valid for 'index'. Parameter name:
>   index

I'm pretty much stumped, it seems logical to me that index 1 will point to the 2nd column, index 2 to the 3rd etc, as it's 0 based?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The error: Could be that SelectedItems only has 1 element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `ManageList.SelectedItems(3).Text`, you're asking it for the forth item selected in your list, not the forth column of the item selected.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)

**EDIT:** Think of it this way: `ManageList.SelectedItems(0)=itms`, which is a string array.  The following example shows how you can access the forth array value of the selected array in the list:

```
Dim itms() As String = ManageList.SelectedItems(0)
If itms.Length>3 Then
    itms(3).DoWhatever
End If
```

Comment: So I need to Dim as new variable as `ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection`, and then access the values of the ListView from that?

Comment: Since your ListViewItem is actually a string array, when you call ManageList.SelectedItems(0), it returns a string array (or whatever it is you put in that position).  Now that you have that array, you can access the values within it.  See my edit above for an example of accessing the forth array element of the selected ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedItems method returns the selected ListViewItem(s). To access the individual columns within, use the [SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Note from the documentation:

> The first subitem in the
>   ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection
>   is always the item that owns the
>   subitems. When performing operations
>   on subitems in the collection, be sure
>   to reference index position 1 instead
>   of 0 to make changes to the first
>   subitem.